# Charged way too much for BigQuery Analysis

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using **Google data studio** to create **mobile analytic reports** using **google Firebase data**, linking with **BigQuery**. We have a dataset created in the report which uses a query to pull data from BigQuery - `SELECT    * FROM table.events_*` which returns **69.4 GB** data (verified in validator). The problem is when we create report using this query in dataset, for each report we are charged for 'BigData Analysis' in Tebibytes, which is way too much. But when we calculate the pricing for query, it is not even $1 for the data that we use.
Not sure why the data is processed in tebibytes. Here are some details about the data table in BigData -

> Table size:   246.69 MB
>
> Number of columns:    57

Tried query with some filters as well, but still returning Tebibytes data for single report. Is reducing or filtering number of columns only way to restrict the data processing? what transactions comes under BigData Analysis? (other than query processing). 
Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please use the BigQuery issue tracker, include project and job ids. Can't debug here with the data provided. https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654

Comment: thanks for the suggestion..

Comment: Tebibytes is a unit of measurement, not an amount. The current charge rate for BigQuery is $5 per "terabyte" rounded pro-rata to the nearest megabyte (see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing), although it appears to be measured internally in tebibytes. What do you mean by "still returning Tebibytes data for single report" - are you getting more data in the results than you expect, or is this related to how much you're being billed per query? If you're expecting <$1 per query, how much are you actually being billed?

Comment: What happens if you go to console.cloud.google.com, and go to bigquery under the main menu, and put in the SQL code directly, what does the processed bytes say the query will be?

Comment: Yes..it seems the query is processing more data than we expected. The data processed from the query in the validator is 69 GB where as when I use the same query in the data studio reports to show the data, it is processing 'BigQuery Analysis: 2.83 Tebibytes' for 2 reports (created 2 reports for 2 different clients), which should be 140 GB approx in reality (considering 69 GB per report). Not sure from where that extra data is processing. Should we rely on the validator to see the exact data processing of the query? or are there any hidden processes happen when we use the bigquery? Thank you